# How can I add an ArrayList to a hash map (as values) and clear said ArrayList afterwards (Java)

Tags: arraylist, hashmap

I want to add an ArrayList of values to a hashmap, and then clear the ArrayList, so that I may use the same ArrayList for other values on different keys of the hashmap.

My attempts led me to either the ArrayList getting a single value, all values from the input I was receiving, or no values at all.

Comment: Are you using Java or what?

Comment: `Map<String, List<Item>> items = new HashMap<>();
items.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(item);` Did you try this way?

Answer (score 0):

```
    Map<String,List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.addAll(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
    
    map.put("first", List.copyOf(list));
    list.clear();
    list.addAll(Arrays.asList(7,8,9));

    map.put("second", List.copyOf(list));
```